# after 20.04 update, mobile phone is not detected on connection with usb cable

Tags: usb, android, 20.04

Previously, on connection with USB cable and allowing files sharing on the phone.The device name appeared in the devices tab in the file manager.But there is no notification on the laptop now,although my phone keeps on charging and it appears if I type lsusb command on the terminal but not in file manager.So how should i access the files?

Comment: You need to enable file sharing in your phone. You will be asked when you connect the phone.

Comment: I enable file sharing when asked..but it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to install gvfs-backends and now my devices are displayed in Nautilus on usb connection

Comment: Thanks! It works fine.

Comment: Does not work for me.